Double factorial primes
Let's say that a number is a double factorial prime if it is a prime and there is a number $n$ such that it is equal to $(n!)! \pm 1$ (here $(n!)!$ is the factorial of the factorial, not the usual $n!!$).
So the double factorial primes are a subset of the factorial primes as defined in this MO question.
In that same question, it is conjectured that there are infinitely many factorial primes because the series $\Sigma \frac{1}{\ln(n!)}$ is divergent and because of the prime number theorem (*). According to this heuristic argument, we could expect that there are finitely many double factorial primes because $\Sigma \frac{1}{\ln((n!)!)}$ is convergent.
Can we prove that conjecture that there are finitely many double factorial primes?
(*) See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime-counting_function_in_terms_of_the_logarithmic_integral for a justification of that heuristic in terms of primes "density function".

That is a very weak heuristic argument.  We certainly expect that there are infinitely many primes of the form $n^2+1$, but $\sum \frac 1{n^2}$ converges.  Just knowing that one standard method for demonstrating infinitude can't work doesn't really mean much.

@lulu your example does not work because it's the series $\Sigma \frac{1}{\ln(n^2)}$ that one should consider, and it diverges.
To apply the same heuristic, we could consider $2^{n^2}$ instead of $n^2$.
That being said, I agree that it is a weak heuristic given that primes are not a random process, although it seems usual to conjecture things based on this assumption.

I think it's only usual to base conjectures one way.  That is, Divergence "implies" infinitude, not the other way round.  (Note: You meant to write that $\sum \frac 1{\log n^2}$ diverges, but your core point is good).

@lulu if you or anyone has an argument justifying why this heuristic should work better in one way than the other that could be an interesting answer.

lulu already gave you a reason why the heuristic works only in one way.  If a sum diverge then necessarily there are infinitely many terms. But if a sum is finite that doesn't imply that there are finitely many terms.

@jjagmath Of course a convergent series can have infinitely many nonzero terms. That's not the point here, the heuristic used on MO is based on the prime number theorem, and the series to be considered is $\Sigma \frac{1}{ln(n^2 + 1)}$ (divergent) not  $\Sigma \frac{1}{n^2}$ (convergent) so what lulu described is not a counter example.

A thumb rule is that double exponential growing functions $f(n)$ probably produce only finite many primes , an example is the Fermat numbers $2^{2^n}+1$ and your example another one. But if there is no concrete reason that there can only be finite many primes of such a form , we usually cannot prove that there are only finite many.

What the author means (and what is actually correct) : We usually use the 1/ln(n)-modelif we want to estimate how many primes a sequence probably produces. If the 1/ln(n)-terms sum up to a finite value , then the expected number of primes is finite , hence we conjecture finite many primes. If the sum however diverges , we conjecture infinite many primes.
